# How to change display name in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I got a simple question , I want to change display name of users as in image and I got no right to change it . How can I change the name ?

[Here is the image](http://postimg.org/image/yocqi47ub/)

Comment: You want to change using code or manually?

Comment: I want to use manual way if possible. If not we can go for coding

Comment: Go to Central Administration -> Manage Service Applications -> User Profile Service Application -> Manage User Profiles -> Find your user profile -> Press edit -> Change "Name" property.

Comment: There is another related question , when I enter the name in assigned to feild it does not appear . Do I have to enter the name ?thanks for your answer .

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean when I make a task and I try to fill up "Assign to " field I could not find the new name I gave for the users I must enter the username. I thank you again for your help :)

Comment: You probably need to wait before some of the synchronization jobs finish their work.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets  How to achieve this in code I mean can all the options are valid? A) SSOM
B)REST
C) JSOM
D) .NET CSOM